# Cypress and file upload using selectFile() with drag n drop option

Tags: javascript, file-upload, cypress, svelte

I'm attempting to test, using cypress, the functionality of a file upload widget.

The cypress tests which I've tried are:

```js
const filePath = './cypress/fixtures/example.jpg'

    cy.get('.dropzone')
    .selectFile(filePath, 
    { action: 'drag-drop',
      force: true, }).trigger('drop', {force: true})
```

and

```js
    cy.get('.dropzone > input[type="file"]').should('exist').invoke('show')
    .selectFile(filePath, {
      action: 'drag-drop',
      force: true,
      log: true,
    })
    .trigger('drop', {force: true})
```

and

```
cy.get('.dropzone')
    .children('input[type="file"]')
    .should('exist')
    .invoke('show')
    .selectFile(filePath, { force: true })
    .then(input => {
      expect(input[0].files[0].name).to.equal('example.jpg')
    })
    .wait(6000)
    .trigger('dragstart', { force: true, 
    dataTransfer: dataTransfer })
    .wait(50)
    .trigger('dragover', { force: true })
    .wait(50)
    .trigger('drop', { force: true })
    .wait(50)
    .trigger('dragend', { force: true })
    .wait(50)
    .trigger('change', { force: true });
```

and

```js
cy.document().get('.dropzone')
    .children('input[type="file"]').selectFile(filePath, { action: 'drag-drop' })
```

and

```js
cy.document().get('.dropzone')
    .children('input[type="file"]')
    .selectFile(filePath, { action: 'drag-drop', force: true })
    .trigger('drop', { force: true });
```

The html that the tests are executing against is:

```html
<div tabindex="0" role="button" class="dropzone  svelte-817dg2" style="">
<input accept="image/*" type="file" name="avatar" autocomplete="off" tabindex="-1" style="display: none;"> 
<p>Drag 'n' drop some files here, or click to select files</p>
</div>
```

I am using this svelte component for the drag 'n' drop file upload - https://github.com/thecodejack/svelte-file-dropzone

In both cases, and every variation on these, the tests never actually upload a file.

However, in the cypress chrome browser, I'm able to manually perform the drag n drop action successfully.

Answer (score 4):

I checked out your code and couldn't get `.selectFile()` to work. Just used the HTML segment you gave, ran it with VS Code live server (I know it's a svelte app, but..).

Using the simplest test, should at least be able to see the file attached to the internal `<input>`.

Note `{action:'drag-drop'}` searches for for the `<input>` within `div.dropzone`.

```js
const filePath = './cypress/fixtures/example.jpg'

cy.get('.dropzone')
  .selectFile(filePath, {action:'drag-drop'})

cy.get('.dropzone')
  .find('input')
  .then($input => $input[0].files)
  // assert some things about the input's FileList...
  .should('have.length', 1)
  .and(fileList => expect(fileList[0].name).to.eq('example.jpg'))
  .and(fileList => expect(fileList[0].size).to.eq(159355))
```

But this fails, which makes me think there's a bug in `.selectFile()`. The other weird thing is the `assert` is green as if passing, but actually throws an AssertionError.

[image]

---

**Update: Adding "input" to selector**

It will work if you add `input` to the `.dropzone` selector, but you also need the `{force: true}` option as the input is hidden.

```js
const filePath = './cypress/fixtures/example.jpg'

cy.get('.dropzone input')
  .selectFile(filePath, {force: true})  

cy.get('.dropzone')
  .find('input')
  .then($input => $input[0].files)
  // assert some things about the input's FileList...
  .should('have.length', 1)
  .and(fileList => expect(fileList[0].name).to.contain('example.jpg'))
  .and(fileList => expect(fileList[0].size).to.eq(159355))
```

[image]

---

If you swap in the older 3rd-party [cypress-file-upload](https://www.npmjs.com/package/cypress-file-upload)
, it works.

```js
// path applied is assumed to be /cypress/fixtures/
const filePathInFixtures = 'example.jpg'  

cy.get('.dropzone')
  .attachFile(filePathInFixtures, { subjectType: 'drag-n-drop' })

cy.get('.dropzone')
  .find('input')
  .then($input => $input[0].files)
  // assert some things about the input's FileList...
  .should('have.length', 1)
  .and(fileList => expect(fileList[0].name).to.eq('example.jpg'))
  .and(fileList => expect(fileList[0].size).to.eq(159355))
```

[image]

That gets the file attached, but probably you need to trigger some event to kick off the actual upload. I can't tell what that would be from the info you gave, but try `input` or `change` to start with.

Comment: Thanks, this is an extremely helpful answer, and I really appreciate the time you put into it. I tried your examples, both using `selectFile` and ` cypress-file-upload` - and while the tests passed, they upload did not happen. I also tried with `.trigger('change', { force: true })`, and `drop`, `dropend`, `input` - none would trigger the upload.

Comment: Yeah, unfortunately my answer only covers the easy part. The hard part is figuring out what event to fire in order to kick off the upload. I'll take a look at https://github.com/thecodejack/svelte-file-dropzone to see if I can spot it.

Answer (score 0):

Many thanks goes to @Fody for providing detailed examples.

However, these still did not work.

The below works, but is flaky. There is a need to `wait` before triggering the event. And I guess the flakiness is due to not waiting long enough.

```
const filePathInFixtures = 'example.jpg'  

    

    cy.get('.dropzone')
      .attachFile(filePathInFixtures, { subjectType: 'drag-n-drop' })
      .wait(2000)
      .trigger('change', { force: true })

    cy.get('.dropzone')
      .find('input', { timeout: 10000 })
      // .wait(1000)
      .trigger('change', { force: true })
      .then($input => $input[0].files)
      // assert some things about the input's FileList...
      .should('have.length', 1)
      .and(fileList => expect(fileList[0].name).to.contain('example.jpg'))
      .and(fileList => expect(fileList[0].size).to.eq(40319));
```